# Is it possible to easily replace nestjs-typegoose with nestjs/mongoose?

Tags: nestjs

I have created several routes in NestJS following a tutorial. However, I have the problem that "nestjs-typegoose" seems to be outdated and not properly compatible with nestjs version 9. I have to install each new npm module with --force or --legacy-peer-deps and now something is not working and I do not know if it is because of this problem. Therefore I want to replace this old library.

Replacing "nestjs-typegoose" with "nestjs/mongoose" doesn't seem to be that easy and the following places doesn't work now:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { TypegooseModule } from 'nestjs-typegoose';
...
TypegooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: getMongoConfig,
    }),
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { ModelType } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/types';
import { InjectModel } from 'nestjs-typegoose';
...
 constructor(
    @InjectModel(UserModel) private readonly userModel: ModelType<UserModel>,
  ) {}
```

**user.model.ts**

```
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { TimeStamps, Base } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/defaultClasses';
export interface UserModel extends Base {}

export class UserModel extends TimeStamps {
  @prop({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @prop()
  passwordHash: string;
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { ModelType } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/types';
import { InjectModel } from 'nestjs-typegoose';
...
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(UserModel) private readonly userModel: ModelType<UserModel>,
  ) {}
```

another service file:

```
import { ModelType, DocumentType } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/types';
...  
async create(dto: CreateReviewDto): Promise<DocumentType<ReviewModel>> {
```

Is it possible to fix this somehow easily, if so can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `nestjs-typegoose` ise using rather older packages. There's [`@m8a/nestjs-typegoose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@m8a/nestjs-typegoose) which forked `nestjs-typegoose` and now maintains an active version of it which should make the swap much easier